# Symfony2 access-control give me 403 error

Tags: symfony

I know that my title is not very clear. I explain me, I create a security:

```
security:
encoders:
   Bundles\UserBundle\Entity\user: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_MENAGE:        [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_EMPLOYE:       [ROLE_ADMIN]
    ROLE_GERANT:        [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
    ROLE_INTERCOMMUNAL: [ROLE_GERANT]

providers:
    main:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        anonymous:      true
        provider:       main
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:
            path:       fos_user_security_logout
            target:     /login
        remember_me:
            key:        %secret%
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: ROLE_MENAGE }
    - { path: ^/resetting, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_MENAGE }
    - { path: ^/EncoderDechet, roles: ROLE_EMPLOYE }
    - { path: ^/VoirConteneurs, roles: ROLE_GERANT }
    - { path: ^/GenererFacture, roles: ROLE_INTERCOMMUNAL }
    - { path: ^/Statistique, roles: ROLE_GERANT }
```

Like you can see in this SECURITY.YML I define a role hierarchy. When I log In with a User who have : ROLE_EMPLOYE as role, I have can have access to /register. But this path must have as role : EMPLOYE, and it give me an 403 : access denied.

Can you explain me where I made a mistake ?

Comment: I'm sorry it was 403

Answer (score 1):

Your role hierarchy looks wrong.

It should be

```
ROLE_B: ROLE_A
ROLE_C: ROLE_B
ROLE_D: ROLE_C
```

So something like

```
ROLE_MENAGE:        ROLE_USER
ROLE_EMPLOYE:       ROLE_MENAGE
ROLE_GERANT:        ROLE_EMPLOYE
ROLE_INTERCOMMUNAL: ROLE_GERANT
```

Which would give you 5 roles going: USER < MENAGE < EMPLOYE < GERANT < INTERCOMMUNAL

If you do need `ROLE_ADMIN` & `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` just add them in there where you need them.

Here is what I use on my current project for example

```
ROLE_INFLUENCER:    ROLE_USER
ROLE_COMPANY:       ROLE_INFLUENCER
ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN: ROLE_COMPANY
ROLE_SITE_ADMIN:    ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:   ROLE_SITE_ADMIN
```

Comment: ROLE_MENAGE:        [ROLE_USER]
ROLE_EMPLOYE:       [ROLE_MENAGE]
ROLE_GERANT:        [ROLE_EMPLOYE]
ROLE_INTERCOMMUNAL: [ROLE_GERANT] like this ?

Comment: You do not need the [ ] characters, otherwise it looks ok